# How to format the given time string and convert to date/time object

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format, java-time

I am getting the time object in the form of a string from a rest service . I need to extract the time and then do some time operation.The given time string is "2015-06-16T14:58:48Z". I tried the below code , to convert the string to the time , however , getting incorrect values.

```
    String time = "2015-06-16T14:58:48Z";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);

    String dateInString = "2015-06-16T14:58:48Z";

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println("Original String : " + time);
    System.out.println("After converting to time : " + formatter.format(date));
```

The output that i am getting is as below:
Original String : 2015-06-16T14:58:48Z
After converting to time : 2015-12-362T02:58:48Z

The converted date somehow is getting wrong value.Please suggest where is the mistake.Thanks.

Comment: Read the [API documentation of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). `Y` doesn't mean what you think it means. Same for `D`. Same for `h`. And the `Z` is not just a letter. It means "UTC timezone".

Comment: @Anupam Before posting this kind of problem, **use example code that works**. Then tweak one step at a time towards your desired ends. Your error ( format pattern not matching input string) has already been handled countless times on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You format string has a couple of mistakes:

- `Y` means the **week year**, not the **year**, which is `y`
- `D` means the day of the **year**. You should have used `d`, which means the day of the **month**.
- `h` means a 12-hour notation time of day. Since you have `14` you should use `H`, which handle a 24-hour notation.

To sum it all up:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.US);
```

Comment: The 'Z' part is wrong. He/she should use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`. Otherwise, The date will be parsed in the date frmat's timezone instead of the UTC timezone.

Comment: *"`Y` means the week year, not the year, which is `Y`"* So, the uppercase "Y" means both? :P I guess you meant: "which is `y`".

Comment: @Tom yup, indeed meant `y`. How embarrassing :-(

Comment: Indeed ... no, just kidding. This happens :).

Comment: Edit: As @JBNizet commented, the format should end with an `X` to properly handle the timezone.

Answer (score 3):

change SimpleDateFormat to this..

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.US);
```

Comment: The 'Z' part is wrong. He/she should use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone

Comment: I live in France, which is in UTC+2. If I parse the date using 'Z' i stead of X, the parsed date will be 2015-06-16T14:58:48+02:00, which is the same as 2015-06-16T12:58:48Z, which is thus two hours before the actual date.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The root cause of the problem is using wrong symbols

- `Y` (which specifies *week-based-year*) instead of `y` (which specifies *year-of-era*)
- `D` (which specifies *day-of-year*) instead of `d` (which specifies *day-of-month*).
- `h` (which specifies *clock-hour-of-am-pm*) instead of `H` (which specifies *hour-of-day*).

Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) page
to learn more about these symbols.

Also, note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

The modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require you to use a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the date-time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. Your date-time string conforms to ISO 8601 standards (or the default format used by [`OffsetDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)).

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2015-06-16T14:58:48Z";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // ########################Extract time information########################
        LocalTime time = odt.toLocalTime();

        // You can also get it as time.getHour()
        // Extract other units in a similar way
        int hour = odt.getHour();

        // Also using time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("a", Locale.ENGLISH));
        String amPm = odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h a", Locale.ENGLISH));

        System.out.println(time);
        System.out.println(hour);
        System.out.println(amPm);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-06-16T14:58:48Z
14:58:48
14
2 PM
```

**Note:**

1. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).
2. For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `OffsetDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
    Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>